# How do I partition my hard drive for a Kubuntu installation on a notebook which already has a Windows 10 partition?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, kubuntu

Lenovo V145-15AST model 81MT000QED with 4gbs of ram and 500 gb hard drive

I had windows 10 installed on it in legacy or bios mode and it crashed on me so i had a fresh kubuntu USB ready 21.04 not LTS and i wanted to install it in uefi but the windows partition still exists in legacy so if i delete it in the kubuntu disk manager and put the partition in ext4 with the mounting point / will it work and how much swap area do i need cause i wanna install windows 7 right after i have 4gbs of ram btw also the partition size is 103712 MB please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Although Ubuntu doesn't care about partitioning type, unlike Windows, the general recommendation is to **use GPT for UEFI** (you necessarily have MBR/"dos" now, a requirement for Windows in BIOS/Legacy mode).

So, the first suggestion is to use Gparted, Devices menu > Create new partition table... > choose "GPT". Please note **this will delete everything in the drive**.

Then understand that **how you boot the installation is how it installs**. So, make sure you're booting in UEFI mode.

Regarding swap, **a separated swap partition is no longer needed**, Ubuntu now uses a swapfile by default. The default settings are fine for the vast majority of users and usage scenarios. The swapfile can also be modified later if needed.

You may at this point select the automatic installation or "something else" to do it manually. If the latter then you must create both the ESP (EFI System Partition), a small ~512MB FAT32 formatted partition at the beginning of the drive (this is the automatic installer's default size, it can be smaller, it stores only very small efi files, the bootloaders) and /, the root file system. Nothing else is needed but you can, optionally, create other partitions like a separated /home. Adjust the size to your needs.

Now, **under no circumstance try to use an unsupported OS like Windows 7 online**. It's **dangerous**, **irresponsible** and now **illegal even if you have a once valid license**! It won't activate. You may install the currently supported Windows 10 that you already have in dual-boot. Besides what was already commented, Windows 7 is not exactly simple to install in UEFI mode, compared to newer Windows versions. So no, definitely NO!